# How to run a program and block its internet usage rights?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a program to open another program and block its internet rights, how to do this with `C#`?
It's like a firewall program.

Comment: Your question is a little unclear, could you give an example?

Comment: It's a restriction for internet access... like Sandboxie
http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb6Ul.png

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link to the [firewall API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366458(VS.85).aspx). Code below blocks any outgoing connections.

```
INetFwRule fire = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(
        Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
    fire.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_BLOCK;
    fire.Description = "Block";
    fire.Direction = NET_FW_RULE_DIRECTION_.NET_FW_RULE_DIR_OUT;
    fire.Enabled = true;
    fire.InterfaceTypes = "All";
    fire.Name = "Block Internet";

    INetFwPolicy2 firePolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(
        Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
    firePolicy.Rules.Add(fire);
```

Check this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/680643/How-to-connect-and-disconnect-internet-connection) too